# Returning only certain properties from an array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

If I have an object such that

```
var object = function(key,text)
{
    this.key = key;
    this.text = text;
}
```

And create an array of these objects

```
var objArray = [];
objArray[0] = new object('key1','blank');
objArray[1] = new object('key2','exampletext');
objArray[2] = new object('key3','moretext');
```

is there a way that I can retrieve only one of the properties of all of the objects in the array? For example:

```
var keyArray = objArray["key"];
```

The above example doesn't return set keyArray to anything, but I was hoping it would be set to something like this:

```
keyArray = [
    'key1',
    'key2',
    'key3']
```

Does anyone know of a way to do this without iterating through the objArray and manually copying each key property to the key array?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This is easily done with the [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```
var keyArray = objArray.map(function(item) { return item["key"]; });
```

If you are going to do this often, you could write a function that abstracts away the map:

```
function pluck(array, key) {
  return array.map(function(item) { return item[key]; });
}
```

In fact, the Underscore library has a built-in function called [pluck](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) that does exactly that.

Comment: IE 8 and below does not support `map`

Comment: The MDN documentation linked above includes a polyfill for IE8 and below.

Comment: function pluck(obj){return obj[this]} allows r.map(pluck,"key")

Comment: @dandavis: agreed, that composes much more nicely (you can call `r.filter(pluck, "key")` to find items with a given key, for example). My version merely approximates what Underscore's `_.pluck` does.

Comment: Sometimes I want to do something similar (keep only certain properties in a JavaScript object): https://stackoverflow.com/a/67591318/470749

Answer (score 4):

```
var object = function(key,text) {
    this.key = key;
    this.text = text;
}

var objArray = [];
objArray[0] = new object('key1','blank');
objArray[1] = new object('key2','exampletext');
objArray[2] = new object('key3','moretext');

var keys = objArray.map(function(o,i) {
  return o.key;
});

console.log(keys); // ["key1", "key2", "key3"]
```

JS Bin Example

**http://jsbin.com/vamey/1/edit**

Note that older browsers may not support [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) but you can easily do this with a `for` loop:

```
var keys = [];

for (var i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) {
  keys.push(objArray[i].key);
}
```

JS Bin Example

**http://jsbin.com/redis/1/edit**

Answer (score 1):

You would want to do something like this:

```
objArray.map(function (obj) { return obj.key; });
```

Here is a JSFiddle to demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Q7Cb3/

---

If you need older browser support, you can use your own method:

JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Q7Cb3/1/

```
function map (arr, func) {
    var i = arr.length;
    arr = arr.slice();
    while (i--) arr[i] = func(arr[i]);
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Note older browsers may not support `map`.

Answer (score 0):

Well *something* has to iterate through the elements of the array. You can use `.map()` to make it look nice:

```
var keys = objArray.map(function(o) { return o.key; });
```

You could make a function to generate a function to retrieve a particular key:

```
function plucker(prop) {
  return function(o) {
    return o[prop];
  };
}
```

Then:

```
var keys = objArray.map(plucker("key"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Really "objArray" is an array that have 3 objects inside, if you want list of keys, you can try this:

```
var keys = [];
for(a in objArray) {
    keys.push(objArray[a].key);
}
```

You have in var keys, the three keys.

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: It is bad practice in JavaScript to use `for ... in` to iterate through arrays.

Comment: for(var a = 0; a < objArray.lenght; a++){..} better, sorry. :)