# Extract a property inside of an array of objects which is inside of another array of objects and have the result as an array of strings

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a TypeScript array of objects with the following structure:

```
const surveyResponses: any[] = [
  {createdAt: new Date(), responses: [{questionId: 'input1', response: 'Bla'}]},
  {createdAt: new Date(), responses: [{questionId: 'input1', response: 'Blo'}]}
];
```

I would like to extract the `response` property inside of the `responses` array and have them as a single array of strings.

Expected result: `['Bla', 'Blo']`

I have tried to follow these advices:

1. [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)
2. [Returning only certain properties from an array of objects in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440403/returning-only-certain-properties-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

I have tried to use `reduce` without luck:

```
responses.reduce((a, o) => (o.responses.map(r => r.response) && a.push(o.responses.map(r => r.response)), a), []);
```

I have tried to use `map` without luck:

```
responses.map(r => r.responses).map(r => r.map(r => r.response));
Result: [["Bla"], ["Blo"]]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `flatMap` to take the `responses` array, take their `response` strings, and combine them:

```js
const surveyResponses = [
  {createdAt: new Date(), responses: [{questionId: 'input1', response: 'Bla'}]},
  {createdAt: new Date(), responses: [{questionId: 'input1', response: 'Blo'}]}
];

const result = surveyResponses.flatMap(
  item => item.responses.map(
    ({ response }) => response
  )
);
console.log(result);
```

Also note that using `any` defeats the whole point of using TypeScript, since it effectively disables type-checking for that expression. When possible, either let TS infer the type of an expression automatically, or denote the type yourself manually when you need to. (In this case, TS can infer the type of `surveyResponses` automatically just fine)

If you can't use `flatMap`, you can spread into concat:

```js
const surveyResponses = [
  {createdAt: new Date(), responses: [{questionId: 'input1', response: 'Bla'}]},
  {createdAt: new Date(), responses: [{questionId: 'input1', response: 'Blo'}]}
];

const result = [].concat(...surveyResponses.map(
  item => item.responses.map(
    ({ response }) => response
  )
));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, it works perfectly. One additional question, how can we achieve this when `flatMap()` is not an available option in our environment? About the types, thanks for the tip, I have added an interface now.

Comment: Great!, thanks a lot for your time and your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, an even simpler option using `flatMap`. You can always polyfill it if its not available.

```
const result = surveyResponses.flatMap(r => r.responses).map(r => r.response)
console.log(result)
```