# Cloning object with specific properties from object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, clone

What is the optimized way to clone one object from another object with specific properties, not all?

Like below we can get values by projection from an object:

```
let tempObject = { 
  prop1 : 'something',
  prop2 : 'something' ,
  other : 'others'
};
//then
let { prop1, prop2} = tempObject;
```

Same way I want to clone a few properties from another object like

```
let oldObject = { 
  p1 : 'something',
  p2 : 'somethig',
  p3 : 'something' 
}
```

Want to make another object from above `oldObject` with only `p1 and p2` those two properties. 
Expected `newObject` will be `{p1 : 'something', p2 : 'somethig'}`.

I know there are many ways to do that but I wanted to know the optimized way with the explanation.

Comment: "Optimized" how? Runtime speed? Code clarity? Conciseness?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51340819/9867451

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for too specific asking? Yeah my concern is Runtime speed firstly

Comment: Are you really going to be doing this hundreds of thousands of times in a tight loop? Suggest writing the clear code first, and ***if*** you have a performance problem at some point that you've identified is down to this (which seems really unlikely), address it then.

Comment: I've done with clear code like I did with basic way. But curiosity !

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Thanks buddy, Selected one from your referred question.

Answer (score 3):

I'd keep it simple:

```
let newObject = {
    p1: oldObject.p1,
    p2: oldObject.p2
};
```

That will also be very, very fast, as you've commented you're thinking in terms of performance.

You could complicate it with a loop:

```
let newObject = {};
for (const name of ["p1", "p2"]) {
    newObject[name] = oldObject[name];
}
```

Or with *property rest* (ES2018, in modern browsers, and supported by transpilers for a long time now) you could copy all but the ones you name:

```
let {p3, ...newObject} = oldObject;
```

But I'd keep it simple in most cases.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir - Good find. The OP seems to be focussing on performance, whereas that focusses on elegance, but...that's a very thin distinction. :-)

Comment: Yeah I've just seen his comment.

Comment: 2nd approach is awesome but I'm not using ES2018. Liked that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [lodash](http://lodash.com) to select only the relevant properties with `_.pick`, like so:

```
_.pick(oldObject, ["p1", "p2"])
```

You can see a working version here: https://jsfiddle.net/W4QfJ/19493/

Or look at: [Filter object properties by key in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750705/filter-object-properties-by-key-in-es6/47038365#47038365)