# How can I select only a few fields when destructuring a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I can't seem to remember how to write this destructuring pattern, could you please help me?

Let's say I have an object like this:

```
{
  id: 'po_495743057439095',
  object: 'payout',
  amount: 18560,
  arrival_date: 1576195200,
  automatic: true,
  balance_transaction: 'txn_32472309478903284',
  created: 1575774863,
  currency: 'eur',
  description: 'STRIPE PAYOUT',
  destination: 'ba_329047329048323',
  failure_balance_transaction: null,
  failure_code: null,
  failure_message: null,
  livemode: true,
  metadata: {},
  method: 'standard',
  source_type: 'card',
  statement_descriptor: null,
  status: 'in_transit',
  type: 'bank_account',
}
```

(this is actually an object from the Stripe API).

I would like to push this object in my custom array, but only keeping 5 fields from it.

I can do:

```
arr.push({
  id: myObject.id,
  object: myObject.object,
  amount: myObject.amount,
  arrival_date: myObject.arrival_date,
  created: myObject.created
})
```

But I would like to know if there is any syntax that would help me achieve the same thing in a shorter way.

Basically I'm pretty sure there is a syntax to do it that requires writing the word 'myObject' only once, writing each key name once, and without creating temporary variables, but I can't remember how.

I'm not asking about writing a specific function, I don't need help for that. I'm just asking if there is a built-in destructuring syntax for doing this, because I'm pretty sure there is but I can't find it, despite searching for quite some time just before.

***Edit:***

The answer I was looking for exists here: [Elegant way to copy only a part of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51340819/elegant-way-to-copy-only-a-part-of-an-object/51340842#51340842)

Comment: If you are not strict about built in methods, you could use the `pick` function of lodash. `pick( myObject, [ 'id', 'object', 'amount', 'arrival_date', 'created'])`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but yes I'm looking for a built-in way :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you can do this just using es6 object destructuring. But you could make use of some es6 functionalities to implement the lodash's `pick` function.

```
Object.assign(
  {},
  ...['id', 'object', 'amount', 'arrival_date', 'created'].map(key => ({
    [key]: myObject[key]
  }))
);
```

```js
    const myObject = {
      id: 'po_495743057439095',
      object: 'payout',
      amount: 18560,
      arrival_date: 1576195200,
      automatic: true,
      balance_transaction: 'txn_32472309478903284',
      created: 1575774863,
      currency: 'eur',
      description: 'STRIPE PAYOUT',
      destination: 'ba_329047329048323',
      failure_balance_transaction: null,
      failure_code: null,
      failure_message: null,
      livemode: true,
      metadata: {},
      method: 'standard',
      source_type: 'card',
      statement_descriptor: null,
      status: 'in_transit',
      type: 'bank_account',
    };

    const newObject = Object.assign(
      {},
      ...['id', 'object', 'amount', 'arrival_date', 'created'].map(key => ({
        [key]: myObject[key]
      }))
    );
    console.log(newObject);
```

Comment: That's the simplest way to do so. Can you please explain [key] in this statement:- 
[key]: myObject[key]?

Comment: Since you are running map on an array, in each iteration key will be 'id', 'object' etc. The the map returns a new object with { id: myObject[id] }, { object: myObject[object] } and so on which is then combined together to form a single object using Object.assign.

Read more about Array.map and Object.assign if you need to know more about how they work.

Answer (score 1):

```
let myObject = {
  id: 'po_495743057439095',
  object: 'payout',
  amount: 18560,
  arrival_date: 1576195200,
  automatic: true,
  balance_transaction: 'txn_32472309478903284',
  created: 1575774863,
  currency: 'eur',
  description: 'STRIPE PAYOUT',
  destination: 'ba_329047329048323',
  failure_balance_transaction: null,
  failure_code: null,
  failure_message: null,
  livemode: true,
  metadata: {},
  method: 'standard',
  source_type: 'card',
  statement_descriptor: null,
  status: 'in_transit',
  type: 'bank_account',
}

const {id, object, amount} = myObject;
```

Now instead of using `myObject.id` you will use `id`.

Comment: Is there any way to change your code in a way that wouldn't require creating those 3 variables in the scope? I tried arr.push({id, object, amount} = myObject) but the whole object gets added

Comment: No, there is not. That is the correct way of destructuring an object. Read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) more about it.

Comment: Actually, there is, I found what I was looking for. You can read here about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51340819/elegant-way-to-copy-only-a-part-of-an-object/51340842#51340842

Comment: @Vincent I am glad you found your solution, but you clearly stated you don't want specific functions, but built in one. :) `I'm not asking about writing a specific function, I don't need help for that. I'm just asking if there is a built-in destructuring syntax for doing this, because I'm pretty sure there is but I can't find it, despite searching for quite some time just before. `

Comment: Ahah :) For me, ({a,b})=>({a,b})(object) is something I consider a built-in javascript syntax with no custom code, but yes, sure, it is a function ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest thing what you can achieve is using `...` operator called spread syntax.

Please find the example here:

```js
const oldArray = [{
  id: 'po_495743057439095',
  object: 'payout',
  amount: 18560,
  arrival_date: 1576195200,
  automatic: true,
  balance_transaction: 'txn_32472309478903284',
  created: 1575774863,
  currency: 'eur',
  description: 'STRIPE PAYOUT',
  destination: 'ba_329047329048323',
  failure_balance_transaction: null,
  failure_code: null,
  failure_message: null,
  livemode: true,
  metadata: {},
  method: 'standard',
  source_type: 'card',
  statement_descriptor: null,
  status: 'in_transit',
  type: 'bank_account',
}];

const newArray = [...oldArray.map(({id, object, amount, arrival_date, created}) => {
  return {id, object, amount, arrival_date, created};
})];

console.log(newArray);
```

Read further here: [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

I hope that helps!