# Destructure object into a smaller object

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I want to create a new object based on anther object but with fewer properties.

I know I can do it by manually assigment like this:

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};
const smallObj = {
  a: obj.a
};

console.log(smallObj)
```

Is there a way to do it with destructuring?

I have tried doing this:

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};
const smallObj = {
  a
} = {...obj}

console.log(smallObj, a)
```

But as you can see, I get the variable `a` to be equal to `1` but `smallObj` is a reference to `obj`.

Comment: Please type the question carefully....

Comment: Alternative duplicate, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22202766/keeping-only-certain-properties-in-a-javascript-object